# Using JMeter tool to test performance of component displaying in UI

Tags: performance, while-loop, jmeter

I need to build a test plan using JMeter tool (While control ) is loop during execution until component is showing in UI and according to that response time will be calculated for any page.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. **Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So you need to analyze the server response and compare the page in 2 cases: when the "component" is present in the "UI" and when it's not there.

If browser "waits" for the component by periodically sending the HTTP requests you can do the same using While Controller and extract the indicator or the "component" presence using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors). When the component will be there - the While Controller will exit the loop.

The whole duration of the waiting along with the logic which triggered waiting can be measured using [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/)

Comment: Thanks @Damitri is there any sample which i can refer to ?

Comment: 1. Official documentation on the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller). 2 Official documentation on [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) 3. [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) article